# Which classes of my application are available in my Arquillian test cases?

Tags: jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I realize that some of the classes that are not added to my shrinkWrap archive are used during running the arquillian test cases which cause problems.

I have a boot function in my application config with a signature like this

> public void boot(@Observes StartupEvent startupEvent,
>                 ExternalContext externalContext, Application application,
>                 ProjectStage deltaspikeProjectStage)

(startUpEvent is sent when JSF is ready and up and running)  and this is not added my ShrinkWrap, but when I am running testcases they calls my boot function.
This unnecessary call ruin every things. When I am commenting this function, my test cases is working fine.

I was thinking that available classes for my test cases should be added to the ShrinkWrap archive with commands like

```
WebArchive webArchive=  ShrinkWrap
                    .create(WebArchive.class, "ROOT.war")
                    .addClasses(CdiTestBean.class,PersistenceListener.class)
```

but it seems that I am wrong. What should I do to make a class unavailable to a shrinkWrap archive!!

Comment: How does your full test and web archive look like? What type of Arquillian container are you using? Is there an exception? Can you provide some more context?

Comment: let me explain the problem again, In my application I have a boot function which is listening to JSF with an Observer (you can find this function in the question). when I run my tomcat and load the application this function will be called. my problem is, when I am running my arquillian test cases this function is calling also(which I don't want to call). I didn't add the class with the boot function to my ShrinkWrap archive, so how arquillian test case find and call this boot function !! I am using Arquillian with CDI and Hibernate on embedded-tomcat7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using embedded container that might be the problem, as all your CDI beans are on the same classpath. Therefore they probably are scanned by the embedded container/cdi implementation. Try with managed version if possible, this should give you proper isolation.

Comment: I was thinking that my test case only aware of the classes that  have been added to my ShrinkWrap archicve, but it seems that you are right. I have created two entity manager, one just for my test case which I included it in my shrinkwrap archice and the other for the whole application ( I have not included this one in my shrinkwrap), and I was getting ambiguous dependency with injecting entity manager in my test case until I write a qualifier for my test entity manager

Comment: is there any way to avoid this types of problems in my embedded container?! I don't want automatic scanning, I want to work only with the classes which have been added to my Shrinkwrap archive

Comment: Don't use an embedded container :-) Why not using a remote one?

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine with managed container, but is really slow.I wonder how long it will take if we want to run around 300 test cases with every Jenkins built

Answer (score 0):

Before returning the `webArchive` add this line:

```
new ZipExporterImpl(webArchive).exportTo(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "myWebArchive.war"), true);
```

it's going to save your web archive into a file in Java's temp system folder.

Extract the war to inspect if all required classes are there.

Calling a method `addClasses(Class... classes)` should add the classes to a war.

Comment: I have a class in my application which is not included in my ShrinkWrap and I don't need it in my ShrinkWrap, but when I am running my test case, I can see a problem in my console related to one of the functions of this class (Unsatisfied dependencies). I wonder if I am not include it in my ShrinkWrap why my test case is able to call one of it's functions

Comment: You should be able to see which method is trying to call a method from the missing class from the stack trace.